# What method do we use to find the solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Find the solution of the initial and boundary value problem

$$u_t(x,t)-u_{xx}(x,t)=0, x>0, t>0, \\ u(x,0)=f(x), x>0,\\ u(0,t)=0, t>0 $$

(The solution should be expressed as an integral at the interval $[0,+\infty)$ of a suitable function.)

We make an odd extension of $f$

$$\overline{f}=f \text{ for } x \geq 0 \text{ and } -f(-x) \text{ for } x<0$$

and we solve the problem

$$u_t=u_{xx}(x,t), x \in \mathbb{R}, t>0\\u(x,0)=\overline{f}(x), x \in \mathbb{R}$$

The solution of this problem is:

$$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4 \pi t}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{\frac{-(x-y)^2}{4t}} \overline{f(y)}dy$$

For $x>0$ we have:

$$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4 \pi t}} \left( \int_{-\infty}^0 e^{\frac{-(x-y)^2}{4t}}\overline{f}(y)dy+ \int_0^{\infty} e^{\frac{-(x-y)^2}{4t}} \overline{f}(y)dy\right)= \dots=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4 \pi t}} \int_0^{\infty} \left[e^{- \frac{(x-y)^2}{4t}}-e^{- \frac{(x+y)^2}{4t}} \right]f(y)dy$$

So the solution of the starting problem is $u(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4 \pi t}} \int_0^{\infty} \left[e^{- \frac{(x-y)^2}{4t}}-e^{- \frac{(x+y)^2}{4t}} \right]f(y)dy, x>0, t>0$

How do we find that:

**The solution of this problem is: **

$$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4 \pi t}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{\frac{-(x-y)^2}{4t}} \overline{f(y)}dy$$

? What method do we use? And why did we take the odd extension of $f$?

Answer (score 1):

Of course use separation of variables:

Let $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$ ,

Then $X(x)T'(t)-X''(x)T(t)=0$

$X(x)T'(t)=X''(x)T(t)$

$\dfrac{T'(t)}{T(t)}=\dfrac{X''(x)}{X(x)}=-s^2$

$\begin{cases}\dfrac{T'(t)}{T(t)}=-s^2\\X''(x)+s^2X(x)=0\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}T(t)=c_3(s)e^{-ts^2}\\X(x)=\begin{cases}c_1(s)\sin xs+c_2(s)\cos xs&\text{when}~s\neq0\\c_1x+c_2&\text{when}~s=0\end{cases}\end{cases}$

$\therefore u(x,t)=\int_0^\infty C_1(s)e^{-ts^2}\sin xs~ds+\int_0^\infty C_2(s)e^{-ts^2}\cos xs~ds$

$u(0,t)=0$ :

$\int_0^\infty C_2(s)e^{-ts^2}~ds=0$

$C_2(s)=0$

$\therefore u(x,t)=\int_0^\infty C_1(s)e^{-ts^2}\sin xs~ds$

$u(x,0)=f(x)$ :

$\int_0^\infty C_1(s)\sin xs~ds=f(x)$

$\mathcal{F}_{s,s\to x}\{C_1(s)\}=f(x)$

$C_1(s)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}_{s,x\to s}\{f(x)\}$

$\therefore u(x,t)=\int_0^\infty\mathcal{F}^{-1}_{s,x\to s}\{f(x)\}e^{-ts^2}\sin xs~ds$